# Get selected <li> to input box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently creating this option where one obtains all the data from the database, and it can see the data when clicking a dropdown list. The only thing is, I would like to click a single `<li>` from that dropdown, and place it in a input box below, so the item can be submitted to a different table.

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Business Objective
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul id="bolist" style="margin-left: 575px;" class="dropdown-menu">
        <c:forEach var="row" items="${objectives.rows}" varStatus="status">
            <li>
                <a href="#/"><c:out value="${row.objective}"/></a>
            </li>
        </c:forEach>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So all the data is in the dropdown there. My `input` looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-8">
    <label class="col-md-11 control-lable">Objective</label>
    <div class="col-md-11">
        <form:input type="text" path="objective" id="inputobjective" class="form-control input-lg"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Output (for each of the selections, i want the selected value to get into the input)
 [image: output]

Comment: You just need to use a `click()` event handler and retrieve whatever value you need from the DOM. Could you please edit your question to show a short sample of what the *HTML output* actually looks like when provided to the client.

Comment: I put a screenshot of it on the bottom of the post!

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
$('#bolist').on('click','li',function(){
  $('#inputobjective').val( $(this).find('a').text() );
});
```

Comment: Mhm, it doesn't seem to do anything when I click a list item :/

Comment: See if it works with `$('#inputobjective').val( $(this).find('a').html() );` on the second line.

Comment: I have already found a solution to this problem! I know use the `<form:option>` to save the data. It's a different approach, but it seems to work for me. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Or skip the whole "detect click on li, then drill down into a" and replace `$('#bolist').on('click','li',function(){` with `$('#bolist').on('click','li > a',function(){` and `$(this).find('a').text()` with `$(this).text()`. (Understanding that the user would then need to click on the anchor tag, as opposed to the whole list item.)